# IPV6 usage study

Tags: network-programming

I have a pretty overview on the TCP/IPv4 stack. I am planning to get into the next version of IP which is IPV6 which is for the future I believe. I really need some valuable inputs from anyone as to which site or link or maybe I can do something practically by using some kind of simulators to learn something like atleast some UDP6 stack or TCP 6 stack.

Any valuable inputs?

Comment: Why do you need simulators?. Just activate IPv6 on your machine. All operating systems have IPv6 support for many years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following ipv6 site - it has links to specifications, ipv6 enabled applications and ipv6 stack implementations:

http://www.ipv6.org/

Answer (score 1):

Although I am a bit late to reply but as I found this question so generally I am replying here.
The best simulation software available at the time of writing this answer is GNS3 and you can download it from [GNS3.net](http://www.gns3.net/download/) for free.
It simulates real routers IOS images and you can create real routing packets environment and learn a lot even for IPv6 routing protocols.
I literally created my CCIE LAB environment through this fantastic software and you can also connect those GNS3 routers to your physical switches.
I also wrote some articles in my blog related to IPv6 and you may read few of the articles below

- [Understanding IPv6 Addressing](http://www.routinglayers.com/understanding-ipv6-addressing/)
- [IPv6 configuration](http://www.routinglayers.com/static-ipv6-address-configuration-using-simple-and-eui-based-ip-addressing/)